# Getting the content from a MailMessage object

Tags: laravel, markdown

I am trying to create a system that will automatically log the content of any email notifications that my site sends to users, against their accounts.

I am doing this by listening for the `NotificationSent` event, which provides me with easy access to the `Notifiable` (the object that I want to store my log entry against) and the `Notification` (the object that defined the message that has been sent).

Using these I am able to get hold of the `MailMessage` object, but I can't work out how to render it. I was hoping it would have a render method but I can't find one. Presumably there is some other object that takes the `MailMessage` and does the rendering. Any clues?

Ideally I'd like the plain text version of the email (the markdown)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution that is doing what I want. I cannibalised some code I wrote for something else, that got me a long way there. There are some steps that I don't completely understand so there may well be some unnecessary bloat in here:

```
class LogNotification
{
    public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
    {
        //getting the MailMessage object
        $mailMsg = $event->notification->toMail($event->notifiable);

        //I think this is getting the additional variables from the 
        //MailMessage that are needed to render the view
        $msgData = array_merge($mailMsg->toArray(),$mailMsg->viewData);

        //I don't fully understand this. I get that the Markdown object is 
        //going to do the rendering, but I don't know why it needs to be 
        //instantiated with an empty View object
        $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));

        //Pass the renderText method the path to the markdown, and the message data
        $msgContent = $markdown->renderText($mailMsg->markdown, $msgData);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone (and if anyone can offer a proper explanation of what is happening when the Markdown object is instantiated, I'd be grateful).